# Needing to extract items from JSON, use them to make another API call

Tags: jquery, image, json, api

Trying to pull info from one JSON datafeed and use that to make another API call, returning a second JSON string.

I am not able to make the second call properly.

Please note that my total JSON and JQUERY experience is about 4 days!

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script type="application/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

 //Get Listing value for item 0 in JSON feed

  $.getJSON('http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/public/shops/textilesandtreasures/listings/active?api_key=nshydhv462pr42t7g36b5nky',
function(data)
{   
       $('#ShopListing').html(data.results[0].listing_id);
       $('Listing1').html(data.results[0].listing_id);

       $.getJSON('http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/public/listings/'+data.results[0].listing_id+'/images?api_key=nshydhv462pr42t7g36b5nky',
       function(data)
        {

          var $img1 = $("<img width='100%' />").attr('src', data.results[0].url_fullxfull);


          $('#ItemImage').empty().append($img1);

        });


});  

})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="ShopListing"></div>

<div id="ItemImage"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**getJSON** uses XmlHttpRequest, meaning it's an asycronous callback.

The solution:

Put the second JSON call in the callback for the first one.

```
$.getJSON('/api', function(data) {
   $.getJSON('/api2', function() {

   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Nesting the calls does not seem to make any difference.  Code updated above.

Comment: So what happens though, any JavaScript errors? Does Firebug/Fiddler show the second call happening? The above code works in *general*, so i suggest maybe your not calling the API correctly? Does the second call work if you execute it by itself? (hard code the params)

Comment: Are you sure it should be `+Listing1+` for the second URL? Shouldn't that be `+data.results[0].listing_id+`?

Comment: @CM - hehe, no problems, glad you got it sorted. happy jQuery'ing! :)

Comment: Also, a note on StackOverflow - don't update your question with what was the correct answer, as if someone comes to this thread later on it will be confusing as the question and my answer will be the same. Just a tip. :)